# Is there a workaround for strong parameter hell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I just inherited a RoR 3.2 app and am trying to get it working on 4.2

I am going to put on my sarcastic hat for a second, just so I can feel better. Instead of having a single line in a single file to protect specific fields from mass-assignment, "Strong" Parameters requires bloating up controllers and heaven help you if a controller uses multiple models or a model is used by multiple controllers or need nested attribute whitelisting. This is the exact opposite of DRY and KISS.

*That is better. Okay, so the question is, besides getting rid of mass assignment completely, which is sounding really good right about now, is there a sane way to use it or get around it. From what I understand that gem that brings back attr_accessible won't work in Rails 5 which is where this app is heading.*

*I understand the Ruby object model and can make a ton of modules that controllers can mixin, but that is just ugly and still error prone.*

*Any advice or hints would be welcome.*

Why is that every new Rails feature involves more boilerplate spread over multiple files? If I wanted Java, I know where to find it. The stupidity of getting rid of the powerful and clean link_to_function in favor of using a tangled mess of callbacks almost made me quit, but adding that function back is trivial. Hopefully when the client wants the inevitable upgrade to Rails 5 I can talk him into something more sane and move things bit by bit to a sane web framework.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is "form objects". There's a great [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects) on them. You may also be interested in the [reform gem](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)

Edit: looks like there's a free version of that railscast episode on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvL_aZt3zyU

Comment: That looks interesting but adding more bloat is not my goal. Thanks though, it is always worthwhile learning about  new gems.